# Transparency works only for one set of boxes

Tags: gnuplot, transparency, histogram

So, I am playing around with gnuplot, and it somehow behaves weird. here is the full code:

```
reset

#set terminal cairolatex pdf input
#set output 'test.tex'
set terminal wxt

poisson(n) = nexp**n/int(n)!*exp(-nexp)
nexp = 3
ax = nexp
ay = 1
bw = 0.2

set xrange[-0.5:12.5]
set samples 13
#set style data boxes
set boxwidth bw absolute
set style fill transparent solid 0.5 border
set xtics 1 
set xlabel '$n$'
set ylabel 'Probabiltity of finding $n$ photons'
set key off

plot '+' using (ax+bw/2):(ay) with boxes lc rgb"green" title 'Fock state with $n = 3$',\
'+' using ($0-bw/2):(poisson($0)) with boxes lc rgb"blue" title 'Coherent state with $\langle n \rangle = 3$'
```

This is the output I get:
[image: output]

For some reason the green box is not transparent in the plot, but transparent in the key. Anyone knows why or how to solve it?
Thanks a lot for any tips.

Comment: Oh, I use gnuplot 4.6 on windows if this is any help

Comment: Ok, I am pretty sure that the problem comes from plotting only one point with '+' using (ax+bw/2):(ay) ... but no idea why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You generate 13 samples and plot 13 boxes at the sample place. Of course you don't see the transparency anymore. Change the first part of your `plot` command to draw a single box only:

```
plot '+' using (ax+bw/2):($0 == 0 ? ay : 1/0) with boxes lc rgb "green"
```